# excel - how to paste multiple ranges, (2 sheets) same interval? work around?

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I want to copy the selected range from the Book 2 sheet seen in the image below to the selected RED Cells in the other sheet to the left of Book 2.

[image]

How can I get these copied cells in Book 2 into the same selected range in the other sheet? It throws the error:

> Cannot paste to multiple selections.

I do have Kutools if necessary.

Comment: You will need to use vba and loop that steps by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will do it:

```
Sub Macro1()

i = 0
num_items_to_copy = 3

Do While i < num_items_to_copy
  Windows("Book2").Activate
  Range("A1").Offset(i * 2, 0).Copy

  Windows("FULL Catalogue.xlsx").Activate
  Range("K3").Offset(i * 2, 0).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

you need to change num_items_to_copy = 3 to equal the actual number of items to copy.

Also, update Windows("FULL Catalogue.xlsx") to match the actual name of your workbook.

To run a macro, hit Alt-F11 to open the Visual Basic window. On the left is a folder iceon called Modules, right click it and select insert module. Paste the macro in the main window, then hit the green play button at the top.